# Client hangs when tries to read back from server tcp

Tags: c, tcp, client-server

i am trying to create a simple tcp server-client. My programm works fine if client sends data to server but when server tries to answer back the whole connection hangs. I am using write()/read() functions .

Server code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define SIZE 700000000


///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


int main( int argc, char *argv[] ) {


  int sockfd, newsockfd, portno, clilen;
  char buffer[256];
  struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;
  int  n;


  /* First call to socket() function */
  sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

  if (sockfd < 0) {
    perror("ERROR opening socket");
    exit(1);
  }

  bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
  portno = 5001;

  serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
  serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);



  if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) {
    perror("ERROR on binding");
    exit(1);
  }

  listen(sockfd, 10);
  clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);

  /* Accept actual connection from the client */
  newsockfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&cli_addr, &clilen);

  if (newsockfd < 0) {
    perror("ERROR on accept");
    exit(1);
  }


  bzero(buffer, 255);

  int readbyte = 0;

  do {

    readbyte = read(newsockfd, buffer, 1024);

    if (readbyte < 0)
    {
      perror("ERROR on reading socket!");
      break;
    }
    if (readbyte > 0)
    {
      //printf("Here is the message: %s\n",buffer);
    }


  } while (readbyte > 0); /* until EOF */



  int writen = write(newsockfd, "I received your message", strlen("I received your message") + 1);

   if (writen<0){
    perror("Error");
   }

   //debug();

  return 0;
}
```

Client code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <netdb.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

#include <string.h>

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

  int sockfd, portno, n;
  struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
  struct hostent *server;
  int mode;
  char *code;
  char buffer[256];
  char *uptr = buffer;
  int i;




  if (argc < 3) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Use:  %s [hostname] [port] [args]\n", argv[1]);
    exit(0);
  }

  portno = atoi(argv[2]);


  /* Create a socket point */
  sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

  if (sockfd < 0) {
    perror("ERROR opening socket");
    exit(1);
  }

  server = gethostbyname(argv[1]);

  if (server == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "ERROR, no such host\n");
    exit(0);
  }

  bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
  serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  bcopy((char *)server->h_addr, (char *)&serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr, server->h_length);
  serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);

  int sock_et = connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr);

  /* Now connect to the server */
  if (sock_et < 0) {
    perror("ERROR connecting");
    exit(1);
  }
 /* some code... */

while (len > 0) {

    int writen = write(sockfd, buf, len + 1);

    if (writen < 0)
    {
      printf("Error writting to socket!\n");
      break;
    }

    len -= writen;
    buf += writen; /* tricky pointer arythmetic */

  }

 printf("Finished writing to server\n");
  bzero(buffer, 256);
  int readbyte;

 do {

     readbyte = read(sock_et, buffer, 1024);

    if (readbyte < 0)
    {
      perror("ERROR on reading socket!");
      break;
    }
    if (readbyte > 0)
    {
      //printf("Here is the message: %s\n",buffer);
    }


  } while (readbyte > 0); /* until EOF */

    printf("%s\n",buffer );




  close(sockfd);


  return 0;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: In both the server and the client you have a buffer of 256 bytes, but you tell `read` that it can read 1024 bytes into that buffer. What will sooner or later lead to buffer overflows and *undefined behavior* and possibly really bad stuff happening.

Comment: You are right didnt noticed! Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude i've changed it but still hangs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Your client code doesn't compile
2. You are never going to get a 0 (EOF) from read while the socket is open (in either the client or server) -- so just add a `break` after a successful read for now.
3. You are not closing the socket in the server
4. In the client, you need to read from `sockfd`, not `sock_et`

There are probably other issues.  It looks like you are trying to use client.c/server.c from here: http://www.linuxhowtos.org/C_C++/socket.htm

If I use those files, it works fine. So start over from them and apply your changes more carefully.